# how to handle more than 2 players with SFML Networking?

Tags: c++, networking, game-development, sfml

i have been working on a multiplayer game in sfml for the past few days, and i came across an issue: my code couldn't handle more than 2 players, as the data cant be received or sent from the third device.

here is my code:

```
unsigned getPlayerData() {
    sf::Packet Packet;
    if (NSocket.receive(Packet) == sf::Socket::Done) {
        sf::Vector2f Vec;
        float i = 0.f;
        std::string name;
        Packet >> i >> Vec.x >> Vec.y >> name;
        Packet << i << Vec.x << Vec.y << name;
        if (unsigned(i) != SelectedPlayer) {
            GamePlayers[unsigned(i)].Name = name;
            GamePlayers[unsigned(i)].setPosition(Vec);
        }
        GamePlayers[unsigned(i)].Enabled = true;
        return unsigned(i);
    }
    return 255;
}

bool setupSharing() {
    std::cout << "S: Host\tC: Connect\n";
    std::string type;
    std::cin >> type;
    switch (type[0]) {
    case 's':
        std::cin >> SelectedPlayer;
        SelectedPlayer = 0;
        NListener.listen(Port);
        if (NListener.accept(NSocket) != sf::Socket::Done) {
            std::cerr << "Network Error\n";
        }
        break;
    case 'c':
        std::cin >> SelectedPlayer;
        if (NSocket.connect(NIp, Port) != sf::Socket::Done) {
            std::cerr << "Network Error\n";
        }
        break;
    }

    std::cout << "Finished";

    GamePlayers[SelectedPlayer].Name = "NULL";
    std::cin >> GamePlayers[SelectedPlayer].Name;

    NSocket.setBlocking(false);

    return true;
}
void sharePlayerData(int i) {
    sf::Packet Packet;
    Packet << float(i) << GamePlayers[SelectedPlayer].getPosition().x << GamePlayers[SelectedPlayer].getPosition().y << GamePlayers[unsigned(i)].Name;
    
    NSocket.send(Packet);
}
```

it fully works when sending and receiving data between the host and 1 connected player, but i cant manage to get data to be sent and received by the third, fourth etc.

Comment: You designed one-to-one network connection, so obviously it works only for 2 players (server and client). Classic approach would be to design a game server (which is not a Player) that can accept connection from multiple clients (Players) on multiple sockets, and manage the data, by saving information received from Players and sending out the info requested by Players.